# Neo4jClient get collection of types from all relations

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to convert a specific query, which works in the Neo4j graphical interface, to an implementation using the Neo4jClient in C#.

I want to get all the relation types of the result nodes in a list. This is possible using the following query:

```
MATCH ()-[relations]-(p)
Where p.name = 'example'
RETURN count(relations) AS relCount, collect(type(relations)) as types limit 10
```

This results in

| relCount | types |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | ["died_in", "has_type", "was_born", "is_identified_by"] |
| 2 | ["has_type", "is_identified_by"] |

I can't wrap my head around using both `relations.type()` in combination with `relations.CollectAs<List<string>>()` when using the client in C#.

```
var q = client.Cypher
                .Match(@"()-[relations]-(p)")
                .Where("p.name = 'example'")
                .Return((relations, p) => new
                {
                    relCount = relations.Count(),
                    types = relations.CollectAs<List<string>>(),
                });
```

So in the end I want to have an object like this:

```
[
  {
    relcount: 4,
    types: ["died_in", "has_type", "was_born", "is_identified_by"]
  },
  {
    relcount: 2,
    types: ["has_type", "is_identified_by"]
  }
]
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use a `.With()` statement for this:

```
var q = client.Cypher
                .Match(@"()-[relations]-(p)")
                .Where("p.name = 'example'")
                .With("count(relations) AS relCount, collect(type(relations)) as types")
                .Return((relCount, types) => new
                {
                    relCount = relCount.As<int>(),
                    types = types.As<List<string>>(),
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried this aswell, but it didn't work initally. The thing is if you start using `WITH` in a neo4j query it seems like you cannot get the variables before the with. So 
```MATCH ()-[relations]-(p)
Where p.name = 'example'
WITH collect(type(relations)) as types
RETURN p, types limit 10```
doesn't work, but
```MATCH ()-[relations]-(p)
Where p.name = 'example'
WITH collect(type(relations)) as types, with p as outNode
RETURN outNode, types limit 10```
does.

Comment: Or in other words, when using `WITH` you select which of the variables you want to use, and you should do that for every variable. Without `WITH` every variable is available.